# How to assign database value to config variable Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, config

I have a variable of ADMIN_EMAIL_ADDRESS which I am using to send emails to admin and I defined it in the config.php file as :

```
$config['ADMIN_EMAIL_ADDRESS'] = 'example@gmail.com';
```

I want to know that how can I overwrite this value by my database value globally without editing my files where I am using this variable.

What exactly I want is that I want to write a query in config.php file to assign database value to this variable. In this way, I have to edit only one file i.e config.php file and not all files where I am using this variable.

I searched for this and found that I can do this by creating a new library and call that library in my files. But for this, I have to edit each file where I am using this variable. Here is the link:

```
https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/wiki/Storing-variables-config-in-database
```

Is there any other simple way to do that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Store https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/wiki/Storing-variables-config-in-database file in library folder create table as show there and insert  ADMIN_EMAIL_ADDRESS as key and admin email as value load this library using auto load

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3874156/loading-custom-config-file-into-a-codeigniter-library see this link

Comment: Can you please tell me which library you are using to send emails ?

Comment: I am using email library for sending emails...

Comment: @Shibon I tried by creating the library and used it in autoload. Now the issue is that it's not overwriting the predefined values with the new db values.